# Get the value of a variable declared in a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I have 2 pages, "signup.php" and "globalfunctions.php". On signup.php, I get all of the info from the form submission, I hash the password (by appending a random string generated in globalfunctions.php), and I use the function `executeSQL` that I defined.

**signup.php:**

```
include('/home/www/portaldev.samgoodman.co/processes/globalfunctions.php');
$singleAppendString = generateRandomAppend(16);
$form_email = $_POST['email'];
$form_password = $_POST['password'];
$form_name = $_POST['name'];
$form_school = $_POST['schoolid'];
$form_grad = $_POST['gradyear'];
$form_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$password_with_hash = $form_password.$singleAppendString;
$hashedPassword = sha1($password_with_hash);

executeSQL("$nextUserQuery", "SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
```

Here is where I would like to get the value of `$nextUserQuery` from the database, but I need to return the value in the function.

```
executeSQL("$insertUser", "INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password, school_id, grad_year, lvl, signup_ip) VALUES ('".$calc_userid."', '".$form_name."', '".$form_email."', '".$hashedPassword."', '".$form_school."', '".$form_grad."', '0','".$form_ip."')");
executeSQL("$insertHash", "INSERT INTO vault (id, hash) VALUES ('".$calc_userid."', '".$singleAppendString."')");
```

**globalfunctions.php**

```
function generateRandomAppend($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function executeSQL($varName, $query) {
    global $varName;
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "hugopak1_spm", "Massavailable1", "hugopak1_spm");
    $varName = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    return $varName;
}
```

Comment: can you explain with some different words? it is harder to get what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Why is there `$varName` parameter in `executeSQL` function?

Comment: I am trying to name a variable in the function executeSQL(), and then call on that variable, so by returning the $varName, I should be able to return the contents of the variable I defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you currently do is not the correct way to get the value returned by `executeSQL` function. Remove `$varName` parameter from `executeSQL` function

```
function executeSQL($query) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hugopak1_spm", "Massavailable1", "hugopak1_spm");
    $varName = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    return $varName;
}
```

and declare a new variable that will hold the returned value

```
$nextUserQuery = executeSQL("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
```

In the above example, the value of `$nextUserQuery` is the value returned by `executeSQL("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1")`. You should apply the same thing to the other two lines as below

```
$insertUser = executeSQL("INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password, school_id, grad_year, lvl, signup_ip) VALUES ('".$calc_userid."', '".$form_name."', '".$form_email."', '".$hashedPassword."', '".$form_school."', '".$form_grad."', '0','".$form_ip."')");
$insertHash = executeSQL("INSERT INTO vault (id, hash) VALUES ('".$calc_userid."', '".$singleAppendString."')");
```